# Display (Sort by, compare product block) to the left?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product

I use magento 1.7 and I wish to change the position of my "sort by" block and "compare" block to left. What should I do to accomplish that?

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what you mean by 'sort by' block? is that in the list view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks All for yours ideas.
I moved many block that i whish to display them in the left like  product_list_related,product_list_related,product_viewed,cart_sidebar
Thats help and it is the solution who i addopted :

I changed the template used in catalog.xml.

Before it is 2columns-right.phtml

page/2columns-right.phtml

and now 2columns-left.phtml

page/2columns-left.phtml

i change the position of product_compare_sidebar and product_list_related to left

I changed in reports.xml product_viewed from right to left

I changed in chekout.xml cart_sidebar from right to left

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Layout moves involve unsetting from original parent & inserting in new parent.

In *`local.xml`* in your custom theme's *`layout`* folder (create if you don't have it), you should add the following:

```
<default>
    <!-- Move compare sidebar block from right to left -->
    <action method="unsetChild" block="right"><child>catalog.compare.sidebar</child></action>
    <action method="insert" block="left"><child>catalog.compare.sidebar</child></action>
</default>
```

Regarding the "Sort By" block - that is a part of the so-called **toolbar** block which contains all of the other controls, and there are additional factors which make this kind of messy to move. The same pattern as above holds true - the block's name in layout is **product_list_toolbar**, the parent block is **product_list**, and you will need to execute these directives in the following handles:

- **catalog_category_default**
- **catalog_category_layered**
- **catalogsearch_result_index**
- **catalogsearch_advanced_result**

Ideally this would involve an `update` layout update directive, but it might not work in this context, as `update`-based directives are processed before all other directives *in the particular handle in which they've been included*, meaning that you would be operating on blocks which haven't been created. You could reduce the number of times that you need to call your directives by using the **customer_logged_out** and **customer_logged_in** handles which tend to execute at the end of layout processing, but this feels like a bit of a kludge.

At least you have some options.

Comment: I am using magento 1.7 and is not using theme’s local.xml. I should add my local.xml in 'app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/' ?

Comment: yes you can add local.xml in your theme layout

Comment: To be clear, yes, local.xml should go into your "highest priority" theme.

Comment: Thanks. I used the catalog.xml of my template and it's work.

Comment: Just be aware that you will need to merge changes from the new catalog.xml into the custom one when you upgrade (within the 1.x branch - so you should be safe, as it is terminating after 1.8)

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

write this code app\design\frontend\default\YOUR_THEME\layout\catalog.xml instead of

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/> 
</reference>
```

Comment: Better to use *`local.xml`*

Comment: ya thats right ...you can also use local.xml

Comment: When i edit the name in catalog.xml my block is  disappeared

Comment: your layout is 3 columns or 2-columns-right?